# Running average on SQL Data Stream

Tags: sql, postgresql, pipeline, moving-average

How do I modify the code below to add a running average of each group without:

1. anything in the query that would force multiple passes (e.g., group by or partition by)
2. potential overflow computing the running average

A group of tuples are all adjacent tuples by id with the same grp value so the running average of measure in its group has to be calculated in a way that the query is executed in a purely pipelined way, needing to scan the table only a single time.

Sample output is given below.

```
-- TABLE Stream
\echo -- creating table "Stream"

drop table if exists Stream;
create table Stream (
    id      int,
    grp     int,
    measure int,
    constraint streamPK
        primary key (id),
    constraint idNotNeg
        check (id >= 0),
    constraint grpNotNeg
        check (grp >= 0)
);

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- POPULATE: add some tuples to table Stream
\echo -- populating "Stream"

insert into Stream (id, grp, measure)
values
    ( 0, 0,  2),
    ( 1, 0,  3),
    ( 2, 1,  5),
    ( 3, 1,  7),
    ( 4, 1, 11),
    ( 5, 0, 13),
    ( 6, 0, 17),
    ( 7, 0, 19),
    ( 8, 0, 23),
    ( 9, 2, 29),
    (10, 2, 31),
    (11, 5, 37),
    (12, 3, 41),
    (13, 3, 43);

\echo -- creating composite type "intRec"

drop type if exists
    intRec
    cascade;
create type intRec as (
    number  int,
    restart boolean
);

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- runningSum_state : accumulator function
\echo -- creating function "runningSum_state"

drop function if exists
    runningSum_state(int, intRec)
    cascade;
create function runningSum_state(int, intRec)
returns int
language plpgsql
as $f$
    declare i alias for $1;
    declare a alias for $2;
    declare j int;
    begin
        if a.restart or i is null then
            j := a.number;
        elsif a.number is null then
            j := i;
        else
            j := a.number + i;
        end if;
        return j;
    end
$f$;

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- runningSum_final : returns the aggregate value
\echo -- creating function "runningSum_final"

drop function if exists
    runningSum_final(int)
    cascade;
create function runningSum_final(int)
returns intRec
language sql
as $f$
    select cast(($1, false) as intRec);
$f$;

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- runningSum : the aggregate function
\echo -- creating aggregate function "runningSum"

drop aggregate if exists
    runningSum(intRec)
    cascade;
create aggregate runningSum(intRec) (
    sfunc     = runningSum_state,
    stype     = int,
    finalfunc = runningSum_final
);

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- pipeline sliging-window query that uses our agggregate function
\echo -- querying "Stream" with running sum

with
    -- look at the neighbour tuple to the left to fetch its grp value
    CellLeft (id, grp, measure, lft) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                coalesce(
                    max(grp) over (
                        order by id
                        rows between
                        1 preceding
                            and
                        1 preceding ),
                    -1 )
        from Stream
    ),
    -- determine whether current tuple is start of a group
    CellStart(id, grp, measure, start) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                cast(
                    case
                    when grp = lft then 0
                    else                1
                    end
                as boolean)
        from CellLeft
    ),
    -- bundle the measure and start-flag into an intRC
    CellFlag(id, grp, intRC) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                cast((measure, start) as intRec)
        from CellStart
    ),
    -- call our runningSum aggregator
    CellRun(id, grp, measure, runningRC) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                (intRC).number,
                runningSum(intRC)
                    over (order by id)
        from CellFlag
    ),
    -- extract the running sum from the composite
    CellAggr(id, grp, measure, running) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                (runningRC).number
        from CellRun
    )
-- report
select id, grp, measure, running
from CellAggr
order by id;
```

**Sample Output**

```
 id | grp | measure |     average      
----+-----+---------+------------------
  0 |   0 |       2 |                2
  1 |   0 |       3 |              2.5
  2 |   1 |       5 |                5
  3 |   1 |       7 |                6
  4 |   1 |      11 | 7.66666666666667
  5 |   0 |      13 |               13
  6 |   0 |      17 |               15
  7 |   0 |      19 | 16.3333333333333
  8 |   0 |      23 |               18
  9 |   2 |      29 |               29
 10 |   2 |      31 |               30
 11 |   5 |      37 |               37
 12 |   3 |      41 |               41
 13 |   3 |      43 |               42
```

(14 rows)

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts. Gordon is a very generous contributor.  If you are struggling with the support that you have received, please query him for continued support.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you would express this as:

```
select t.*,
       avg(measure) over (partition by grp order by id) as group_running_avg
from t;
```

You have to trust the execution plan, but you can help it along with an index on `(grp, id, measure)`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Thank you

Comment: @torzihp . . . SQL is not a procedural language.  You have to depend on the optimizer to choose the best execution path.